# Laravel 4 VS Netbeans CSS getting 404

Tags: php, css, laravel-4, http-status-code-404, netbeans-8

I have installed `Laravel 4` On win-8.1 with the instructions from the Laravel [Documentaion](http://laravel.com/docs/quick) and I'm developing using Netbeans-8.

I have placed the **CSS** folder under the **public** folder as many suggested that here as this:
`Laravel/public/css/style.css`.

 And trying to call the **css** file in the **master layout** like this (again as was suggested here):

```
<head>
    {{ HTML::style('css/style.css'); }}
</head>
```

But still getting 404. What am I doing wrong??

Comment: When you render the page it should have link tags with the CSS, is the path right there or it's still broken

Comment: I have The link tag rendered with href="http://localhost:100/css/style.css" but I get a 404 on this file.

Comment: You should put a forward slash in front of css to ensure it is going to the root of the directory so your code should look like this...

{{ HTML::style('/css/style.css'); }}

Comment: so it's rendering the path from the document root of your web server instead of the root of the framework. Maybe using @CheckeredMichael suggestion would help, if not, check your config where the root paths are defined

Comment: thanks @CheckeredMichael. I have already tried that but it behaves the same.

Comment: Try checking out the error logs in laravel/app/storage/logs/laravel.log and see if that tells you where it's trying to look for the css file.

Comment: @CheckeredMichael No log that shows any search for that file.

Comment: With the 404 error, is it a Laravel specific error saying that the css file can not be found, or is it an error saying the actual index page can't be found? Reason why I'm asking is because the default port for Laravel is 8000 and your going to port 100. So just making sure you are going to the correct port which was set...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I **found** what the problem was.
In the Netbeans configuration for the Project I had To the Select the **public** folder as the **"Web root"** and not the ***Laravel*** folder.
@RoyalBg & @chCheckeredMichael Thanks for your Help! I learnt a thing or two from your comments.